# Facing problems in python

Tags: python, syntax, compiler-errors

Code:

```
import socket
import struct
from datetime import datetime

s = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, 8)
dict = {}
file_txt = open("dos.txt", 'a')
file_txt.writelines("**********")
t1 = str(datetime.now())
file_txt.writelines(t1)
file_txt.writelines("**********")
file_txt.writelines("n")
print
"Detection Start ......."
D_val = 10
D_val1 = D_val + 10
while True:
 pkt = s.recvfrom(2048)
 ipheader = pkt[0][14:34]
 ip_hdr = struct.unpack("!8sB3s4s4s", ipheader)
 IP = socket.inet_ntoa(ip_hdr[3])
 print
 "Source IP", IP
 if dict_has.key(IP):
     dict[IP] = dict[IP] + 1
     print
     dict[IP]
     if (dict[IP] > D_val) and (dict[IP] < D_val1):
         line = "DDOS Detected "
         file_txt.writelines(line)
         file_txt.writelines(IP)
         file_txt.writelines("n")
 else:
    dict[IP] = 1
```

When compiling i have facing a error
Error:

raceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/Desktop/Detect/./Detectddos.py", line 24, in 
if dict_has.key(IP):
NameError: name 'dict_has' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have made a spelling mistake in the if statement

```
if dict_has.key(IP):
```

should be

```
if dict.has_key(IP):
```

refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-has_key/ for more.

dict.has_key() has removed from Python 3.x

instead use

```
if IP in dict:
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/Detect/./Detectddos.py", line 24, in <module>
    if dict.has_key(IP):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key

Comment: I have changed the answer please check

Comment: CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/Detect/./Detectddos.py", line 18, in <module>
    pkt = s.recvfrom(2048)
KeyboardInterrupt